# What's the equivalent of the aws cli --query flag with golang aws sdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

I can't figure out what's the `aws-sdk-go(-v2)` equivalent of the `--query` flag with the aws cli.

For instance, what would be the equivalent of this aws cli command (returning the policy with the name `my-policy-name` ) ?

```
aws iam list-policies --query 'Policies[?PolicyName==`my-policy-name`]'
```

Do I have to fetch all policies then "manually" iterate over the results as long as I don't find a match ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent of the awscli's `--query` option in any AWS SDK that I'm aware of.

That option is implemented client-side in the awscli and is essentially a JSON parsing/querying engine, implemented using [jmespath](https://jmespath.org/), that filters results from the underlying AWS service API.

Answer (score 0):

You should understand that the vast majority of our AWS SDK APIs are "wrappers" around service REST APIs. In some cases, various SDKs will create custom APIs for a service, notably DynamoDB.

If you look at IAM's ListPolicies action reference, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ListPolicies.html, you'll note that it has no such filter capability. Therefore, there is no way to filter policies within the request.